# horizontal ScrollView is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When adding horizontal={true} to my scrollview, I thought that would be enough to be able to scroll sideways. For some reason, even though there is enough content to scroll to, the images will not scroll continuously. If you copy and paste this code into snack.expo.io you will see what I mean.

I am not sure what is causing this issue, as I know the normal scrollview vertically works fine and scrolls like normal. I have also tried using nestedScrollenabled to true

Any insight at all is appreciated more than you know!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View, useWindowDimensions, Dimensions, Image, Animated, PanResponder, 
        TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, ImageBackground, Platform} from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';


import {
  scale,
  verticalScale,
  moderateScale,
  ScaledSheet,
} from 'react-native-size-matters';

import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const Images = [
  { id: '1', uri: require('./assets/snack-icon.png'), text: 'Test' },
  { id: '2', uri: require('./assets/snack-icon.png') /*text: "Test"*/ },
  { id: '3', uri: require('./assets/snack-icon.png') /*text: "Test"*/ },
  { id: '4', uri: require('./assets/snack-icon.png') /*text: "Test"*/ },
]

const pressableTest = () => {
  let textlog = '';
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
};

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  renderImagesHorizontal = () => {
    return Images.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            width : '150%',
            paddingLeft: scale(10),
            paddingRight: scale(10),
            paddingBottom: scale(15),
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('VenueDetails')}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={item.uri}
              style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: scale(225),
                shadowColor: '#000',
                shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 4 },
                shadowOpacity: 1,
              }}
              imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  bottom: 10,
                  left: 10,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  alignItems: 'flex-start',
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>Name</Text>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <Text style={styles.category}>Category</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.dot}>⬤</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.money}>$$</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.dot}>⬤</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.starRating}>★★★</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

renderImagesVertical = () => {
    return Images.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <View style={{ paddingLeft: scale(10), paddingRight: scale(10), paddingBottom: scale(20) }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('VenueDetails')}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={item.uri}
              style={{ width:'100%', height: scale(125), 
              shadowColor: '#000',
              shadowOffset: {width: 1, height: 7},
              shadowOpacity: 1,}} imageStyle = {{ borderRadius: 20}}>
              
              <View
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  bottom: 10,
                  left: 10,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  alignItems: 'flex-start',
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>Name</Text>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <Text style={styles.category}>Category</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.dot}>⬤</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.money}>$$</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.dot}>⬤</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.starRating}>★★★</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

  
  
  state = {
    search: '',
  };

  updateSearch = (search) => {
    this.setState({ search });
  };

  render() {

    const { search } = this.state;

    return (
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#272933', horizontal: 'true' }}>
      
       <View style={{flexDirection:'row', marginTop: scale(20)}}>
      {/*this will proabbly say somethign different and probably have a different look to it but you get the idea
        I was also trying to add a shadow to this but couldnt figure it out. */}
        <Text style={{marginTop: scale(30) ,fontSize: scale(40), fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#FFFFFF', paddingLeft: scale(20)}}>
            Home
        </Text>
        <View style={{paddingTop: scale(40), paddingLeft: scale(155)}}>

        </View>
      </View>

      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
        value={search}
        round='true'
        containerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#272933', borderBottomColor: 'transparent', borderTopColor: 'transparent', 
        paddingLeft: scale(20) , paddingRight: scale(20)}}
        inputContainerStyle={{height: scale(30),  width: scale(310), backgroundColor: '#3A3B3C'}}
        searchIcon={() => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="glass-mug-variant" size={25} color='#87909A'/>}
        clearIcon= 'null'
      />
     
      
       <ScrollView
       horizontal={true}
>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection : 'row', marginTop: 15 }}>{this.renderImagesHorizontal()}</View>
      </ScrollView>  

      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 15 }}>{this.renderImagesVertical()}</View>
     
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = ScaledSheet.create({
  starRating: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: '20@s',
    textShadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    textShadowRadius: 2,
    textShadowColor: '#000',
  },

  category: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: '20@s',
    textShadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    textShadowRadius: 2,
    textShadowColor: '#000',
  },
  name: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: '25@s',
    textShadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    textShadowRadius: 2,
    textShadowColor: '#000',
  },
  dot: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: '5@s',
    paddingLeft: '5@s',
    paddingRight: '5@s',
    textShadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    textShadowRadius: 2,
    textShadowColor: '#000',
  },
  money: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: '20@s',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in android you must add `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` to Enables nested scrolling for Android API level 21+. see [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled-android)

```js
<ScrollView> 
         
   <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
            
   </ScrollView> 

</ScrollView>
```

try snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/nested-scroll?platform=android) (test in android & ios not web)

[image]

Comment: I have tried this as well, it did not change anything. I am also using an iphone.

Comment: in renderImagesHorizontal set view fixed width not '150%'

Comment: i update my answer you can try the snack above.